# Disable an element until other input fields are valid

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I am working on an HTML5 form with javascript validation. I would like to disable a select element until several input boxes contain valid data. Here's my simplified HTML:

```
<input type="number" pattern="[0-9]{2}" min="1" max="100" id="num1" required onchange="valid(this)" />
<br />
<input type="number" pattern="[0-9]{2}" min="1" max="100" id="num2" required onchange="valid(this)" />
<br />
<input type="number" pattern="[0-9]{2}" min="1" max="100" id="num3" required onchange="valid(this)" />
<br />
<select id="drop" disabled>
    <option>disabled until input boxes are valid</option>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
</select>
```

Here's the simplified javascript:

```
function valid(obj) {
    if ((obj.validity) && (!obj.validity.valid)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

var numA = document.getElementById("num1"),
    numB = document.getElementById("num2"),
    numC = document.getElementById("num3");

if (valid(numA) && valid(numB) && valid(numC)) {
    document.getElementById("drop").disabled = false;
}
```

and here's my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EV88V)

Can this be accomplished with plain 'ol javascript? As I am still trying to learn Javascript, I am not yet familiar with JQuery.

Any time the input field content changes I would like to validate the input. Then it would need to check if all other input fields (num1, num2, num3) are valid. If, and only if, all are valid it sets disabled = false on the select element.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You'll need to do this check each time there is a change to the other inputs. What happens if, after enabling the #drop element, one of the other inputs becomes invalid through user interaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the answers so far are right on, but in case you don't want to add the onchange attribute to each input here's an alternative:

```
function valid(obj) {
    return !(obj.validity && !obj.validity.valid);
}

var inputs      = document.querySelectorAll('input'),
    inputLength = inputs.length,
    i;

var checkValidity = function() {
    var totalValid = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < inputLength; i++) {
        input = inputs[i];
        if (valid(input)) {
            totalValid += 1;
        }
    }

    document.getElementById('drop').disabled = (totalValid !== inputLength);
}

for (i = 0; i < inputLength; i++) {
    input = inputs[i];
    input.addEventListener('blur', checkValidity, false);
}
```

This just adds an blur event listener to each input and it dynamically changes the disabled on the dropdown depending on all the inputs validity. If you eventually have the dropdown with a required attribute, you'll run into a bit of issues, so you'd probably want to remove that input from the `inputs` array.

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EV88V/10/

Comment: And this way you don't need to know or type out the id's for each input (thus ultimately minimizing your code).

Comment: And lastly, the pattern attribute doesn't seem to be working properly but it seems to be a jsfiddle issue, as the html and js look well formed for it. However, if you want at least two numbers and you're already using a min/max (though I doubt this is a real case scenario), you can always just make your min 10.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative solution. As I'm learning Javascript, I have just come across the information that it is not good practice to place Javascript inline with your HTML (even if it is just a small event handler). Therefore, I've awarded you with the "accepted answer"

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<input type="number" pattern="[0-9]{2}" min="1" max="100" id="num1" required onchange="check()" />
<br />
<input type="number" pattern="[0-9]{2}" min="1" max="100" id="num2" required onchange="check()" />
<br />
<input type="number" pattern="[0-9]{2}" min="1" max="100" id="num3" required onchange="check()" />
```

then

```
function valid(obj) {
    //simplified version
    return !obj.validity || obj.validity.valid;
}


var numA = document.getElementById("num1"),
    numB = document.getElementById("num2"),
    numC = document.getElementById("num3");

function check() {
    document.getElementById("drop").disabled = !valid(numA) || !valid(numB) || !valid(numC);
}
check();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2HBH9/)

Keep the script at the bottom of the page to make sure that when `document.getElementById` is executed the element will be already present in the dom. In jQuery you need to place the script in `No Wrap - Body`(Second dropdown in left panel)

Comment: I'd personally amend the `valid()` function to: `return !(obj.validity && !obj.validity.valid);` for simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

Here is answer for you. You need to check condition if all inputs are valid every time when you change input value.

Here is edited version

HTML

```
<input type="number" pattern="[0-9]{2}" min="1" max="100" id="num1" required onchange="check()" />
<br />
<input type="number" pattern="[0-9]{2}" min="1" max="100" id="num2" required onchange="check()" />
<br />
<input type="number" pattern="[0-9]{2}" min="1" max="100" id="num3" required onchange="check()" />
<br />
<br />
<select id="drop" disabled>
    <option>disabled until input boxes are valid</option>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
</select>
```

And here is JS

```
function valid(obj) {
    if (obj.validity && !obj.validity.valid) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

    var numA = document.getElementById("num1"),
        numB = document.getElementById("num2"),
        numC = document.getElementById("num3");
function check(){

    if (valid(numA) && valid(numB) && valid(numC)) {
        document.getElementById("drop").disabled = false;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to check Nowrap - in head on JSfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code simplified at **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/promatik/EV88V/4/)**

This code is going to switch the state of your `dropdown list` to `enabled` if everything is valid, and back to `disabled` if the user turn the inputs to invalid.

**JS:**

```
function valid(obj) {
    return !( obj.validity && !obj.validity.valid )
}

function testValidity() {
    document.getElementById("drop").disabled = !(
        valid( document.getElementById("num1") ) && 
        valid( document.getElementById("num2") ) && 
        valid( document.getElementById("num3") )
    );
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<input ... onchange="testValidity()" ... />
```